# Math.pow not working when variable is of type int

Tags: java, int, double, type-conversion

My program has a line where it calculates compound interest based on a formula which uses the `Math.pow` method.

When the variable `loanRate` was declared as an `Integer` in the original version of the program below the formula would not work at all and would just return a 0;

I changed `loanRate` to a `Double` as you can see below and for some reason now the program is working.

Sorry if this a very simple question I just have no idea why the `Math.pow` method would not work with my `Int` and if there is a general principle behind using `Math.pow` that im missing?

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
// Variables & Constants
int principle, i;
double simpleInt, compoundInt, difference, loanRate;

// Prompts user to enter principle and rate
System.out.print("Enter Principle: "); // keep print line open
principle = console.nextInt();
System.out.println();

System.out.print("Enter Rate: "); 
loanRate = console.nextDouble();

// Header


// Caculates and Outputs Simple, Compound and Difference for the loan
// in 5 year intervals from 5 to 30

for (i = 5; i <= 30; i = i + 5 )
{
    simpleInt = principle * loanRate/100 * i;
    compoundInt = principle * ((Math.pow((1 + loanRate/100),i))-1);
    difference = compoundInt - simpleInt;


    System.out.printf("\n %7d %7.2f %7.2f %7.2f", i, simpleInt, compoundInt, difference);
}
```

Comment: It's just because you were performing integer division.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`compoundInt = principle * ((Math.pow((1 + loanRate/100),i))-1);`

`loanRate/100` here is the key, as `loadRate` is < 100 than result of such devision will be 0. Change this to `loanRate/100.0` and that will fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks a million - that makes perfect sense now! :)